# Please install the \"intl\" extension for full localization capabilities

Tags: php, symfony, icu, intl

Im using macOs Sierra with PHP 7 installation. Ive installed ICU and also Intl in order to use symphony's Intl component.

Im trying to do this:

```
$localCurrency = new NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$localCurrency = $localCurrency->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE);
```

But I'm getting this error:

The Symfony\Component\Intl\NumberFormatter\NumberFormatter::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'en_US' behavior is not implemented. Only the locale "en" is supported.  Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.

The thing is I have intl and ICU installed, its visible in both `php -i` and also in `phpinfo();`.

Also, Ive installed the intl component to the symphony, it is also visible in vendor.

So I really have no idea what is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried enable the intl extension from `php.ini`?

Comment: Yep, as mentioned above, it was enabled and loaded. Ive posted answer bellow.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the problem was with the use statement, i should have just `use NumberFormatter;` instead of that symphony one, as its a polyfill only.

Now its working fine.